# Redmine+Bundler - method_missing "has_key?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

here is the problem details :

```
undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:77:in `add'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:371:in `push'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine.rb:153
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:301:in `map'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine.rb:152
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:5
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/environment.rb:20
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Gemfile :

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "rails", "2.3.11"
gem "rack", "1.1.1"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"
gem "rubytree"
gem "coderay",  "~> 0.9.7"
```

rubygem version:
1.3.6

by the way i tried menu_manager.rb patch file but it returned an error:
http://www.redmine.org/attachments/5368/menu_manager.patch

```
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
diff --git a/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb b/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb
            ^
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
diff --git a/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb b/lib/redmine/menu_manager.rb
                                          ^
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/lib/redmine.rb:2
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:5
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in `load'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/config/environment.rb:20
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/redmine-1.2.0/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RVM should just solve this. Install [RVM](https://rvm.io) and save your time.

Comment: even if i have multiple ruby project with different gems specs ?

Answer (score 0):

in your Gemfile, set rubytree version to 0.7.0

```
gem "rubytree", "0.7.0"
```